# Migration from Spring Boot 3.0.x to 3.1.x breaks Autowiring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, testing

I am migrating from SpringBoot 3.0.11 to SpringBoot 3.1.4
Up to now I got a warning on servlet registration what from 3.1 on causes an error.
I changed the code as follows to keep the same behaviour.
But now Autowiring is broken.

Any Tipps, what I am doing wrong

This was the code I had in SpringBoot 3.0.11

```
@EnableConfigurationProperties({ DataSourceMonitoringProperties.class})
public class DataSourceServletConfiguration {
    
    public static final String DATASOURCE_MONITORING_PATH = "/datasource";

    @Bean(name = Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
    public Servlet monitoringDatasourceServlet(ServletContext servletContext, DataSourceMonitoringProperties dataSourceMonitoringProperties) {
        RequestDispatcher namedDispatcher = servletContext.getNamedDispatcher(Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME);
        if (namedDispatcher != null) {
            return new DataSourceMonitoringServlet();
        }

        DataSourceMonitoringServlet monitoringDatasourceServlet = new DataSourceMonitoringServlet();
        monitoringDatasourceServlet.setJavamelody(null != servletContext.getFilterRegistration("javamelody"));
        Dynamic monitoringDataSourceServletDynamic = servletContext.addServlet(Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME, monitoringDatasourceServlet);
        monitoringDataSourceServletDynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        monitoringDataSourceServletDynamic.setAsyncSupported(true);
        monitoringDataSourceServletDynamic.addMapping(DATASOURCE_MONITORING_PATH);


        return monitoringDatasourceServlet;
    }
```

I had to changed it to the following to keep it compatible with Springboot 3.0.11

**monitoringDatasourceServletRegistration.setIgnoreRegistrationFailure(true);**

```
    @Bean(name = Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
    @ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
    public ServletRegistrationBean<DataSourceMonitoringServlet> monitoringDatasourceServlet(ServletContext servletContext, DataSourceMonitoringProperties dataSourceMonitoringProperties) throws ServletException {
        RequestDispatcher namedDispatcher = servletContext.getNamedDispatcher(Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME);
        if (namedDispatcher != null) {
            ServletRegistrationBean<DataSourceMonitoringServlet> servletRegistrationBean = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(new DataSourceMonitoringServlet());
            servletRegistrationBean.onStartup(servletContext);
            return servletRegistrationBean;
        }

        DataSourceMonitoringServlet monitoringDatasourceServlet = new DataSourceMonitoringServlet();
        monitoringDatasourceServlet.setJavamelody(null != servletContext.getFilterRegistration("javamelody"));
        Dynamic monitoringDataSourceServletDynamic = servletContext.addServlet(Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME, monitoringDatasourceServlet);
        monitoringDataSourceServletDynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        monitoringDataSourceServletDynamic.setAsyncSupported(true);
        monitoringDataSourceServletDynamic.addMapping(DATASOURCE_MONITORING_PATH);
        
        ServletRegistrationBean<DataSourceMonitoringServlet> monitoringDatasourceServletRegistration = new ServletRegistrationBean<>(monitoringDatasourceServlet, DATASOURCE_MONITORING_PATH);
        monitoringDatasourceServletRegistration.onStartup(servletContext);
        ** monitoringDatasourceServletRegistration.setIgnoreRegistrationFailure(true); **
        monitoringDatasourceServletRegistration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        monitoringDatasourceServletRegistration.setAsyncSupported(true);


        return monitoringDatasourceServletRegistration;
    }
```

During Test Execution the Servlet is called and causes a NUllPointer at

**data.setCollectedDatasourceTraces(datasourceMetricsCollector.collectDatasourceMetrics());**

```
public class DataSourceMonitoringServlet extends GenericServlet {

    @Autowired
    private DatasourceMetricsCollector datasourceMetricsCollector;
    private boolean javamelody;

    public HtmlReportData datasourceReport() {
        // curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" http://localhost:8080
        HtmlReportData data = new HtmlReportData();
        data.setCollectedDatasourceTraces(datasourceMetricsCollector.collectDatasourceMetrics());
        data.setFindLockRows(datasourceMetricsCollector.collectRecordLockInfo());
        return data;
    }
```

This is the Stacktrace I get on Testexecution

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "de.mydomain.framework.monitoring.datasource.collector.DatasourceMetricsCollector.collectDatasourceMetrics()" because "this.datasourceMetricsCollector" is null
    at de.mydomian.framework.monitoring.datasource.html.report.DataSourceMonitoringServlet.datasourceReport(DataSourceMonitoringServlet.java:40) ~[classes/:na]
    at de.mydomain.framework.monitoring.datasource.html.report.DataSourceMonitoringServlet.service(DataSourceMonitoringServlet.java:48) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:764) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$ChainEnd.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1665) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.WebSocketUpgradeFilter.doFilter(WebSocketUpgradeFilter.java:170) ~[websocket-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.lambda$doFilterInternal$3(FilterChainProxy.java:231) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:365) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter.doFilter(AuthorizationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:126) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:120) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:100) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:179) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:107) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:93) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter.doFilterInternal(CsrfFilter.java:117) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:82) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderFilter.java:69) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:62) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter.doFilterInternal(DisableEncodeUrlFilter.java:42) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:374) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:233) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:191) ~[spring-security-web-6.1.1.jar:6.1.1]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:352) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:268) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:116) ~[spring-web-6.0.12.jar:6.0.12]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.doFilter(FilterHolder.java:202) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$Chain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1635) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:527) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:131) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:578) ~[jetty-security-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:223) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:1570) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:221) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1381) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:176) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:484) ~[jetty-servlet-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:1543) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:174) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1303) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:129) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:122) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:563) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel$RequestDispatchable.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:1598) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.dispatch(HttpChannel.java:753) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:501) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:282) ~[jetty-server-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:314) ~[jetty-io-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:100) ~[jetty-io-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectableChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectableChannelEndPoint.java:53) ~[jetty-io-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:969) ~[jetty-util-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.doRunJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:1194) ~[jetty-util-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$Runner.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:1149) ~[jetty-util-11.0.16.jar:11.0.16]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Your code is strange. Your `DataSourceMonitoringServlet` needs to be a bean to be eligible for autowiring. I also don't get why the `ServletContext` is there. You should have 2 beans nothing more nothing less 1 for the servlet and one for the registration. Anything else is overkill/wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is strange and complex. You should have 2 simple beans 1 for the servlet and 1 for the registration. Everything else you added is clutter.

```java
public static final String DATASOURCE_MONITORING_PATH = "/datasource";

@Bean(name = Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
@ConditionalOnMissingBean(name = Const.DATASOURCE_SERVLET_BEAN_NAME)
public DataSourceMonitoringServlet monitoringDatasourceServlet(DataSourceMonitoringProperties dataSourceMonitoringProperties, ServletContext ctx) {
    var monitoringDatasourceServlet = new DataSourceMonitoringServlet();
    monitoringDatasourceServlet.setJavamelody(null != ctx.getFilterRegistration("javamelody"));
    return monitoringDatasourceServlet;
}

@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean< DataSourceMonitoringServlet > servletRegistation(DataSourceMonitoringServlet servlet) {
 var registration = new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, DATASOURCE_MONITORING_PATH);
 registration.setLoadOnStartup(1);
 return registration;

}
```

Spring Boot will handle the registatration of this beans and servlet in the context. You shouldn't be doing this yourself especiallly not in an `@Bean` method.